# Solution of a manipulated equation vs the maximum eigenvalue and eigenvector of a non-negative matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues, eigenvector, nonnegative-matrices

Lets assume we have the following equation:

$AU=\lambda U \Rightarrow\left[
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
0 &A_{12}&A_{13}\\
\hline
A_{21}& 0& A_{23}\\
\hline
A_{31}&A_{32}&0
\end{array}
\right]\left[
\begin{array}{c}
u_1\\
\hline
u_2\\
\hline
u_3\\
\end{array}
\right]=\lambda \left[
\begin{array}{c}
u_1\\
\hline
u_2\\
\hline
u_3\\
\end{array}
\right]$

where the left matrix, shown by $A$, is a non-negative irreducible block matrix and $\left[
\begin{array}{c}
u_1\\
\hline
u_2\\
\hline
u_3\\
\end{array}
\right]$ is a vector that is partitioned into subvectors $u_1$, $u_2$ and $u_3$. Clearly, this vector is the right eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue of $\lambda$.

I want to find a solution for $V$ and $\mu$ in the following equation versus $\lambda$ and $U$. In particular, I am looking at the case where $\lambda$ is the dominant eigenvalue of $A$ which, according to Perron Frobenius Theorem, is real and positive with positive eigenvector $U$.

$\left[
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
0 &A_{12}&A_{13}\\
\hline
\mu A_{21}& 0& A_{23}\\
\hline
\mu A_{31}&\mu A_{32}&0
\end{array}
\right]\left[
\begin{array}{c}
v_1\\
\hline
v_2\\
\hline
v_3\\
\end{array}
\right]=\mu \left[
\begin{array}{c}
v_1\\
\hline
v_2\\
\hline
v_3\\
\end{array}
\right]$

This problem is related to my PhD research and any suggestion is highly appreciated.